# Uploading 10,000,000 files to Azure blob storage from Linux

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have some experience with S3, and in the past have used `s3-parallel-put` to put many (millions) small files there. Compared to Azure, S3 has an expensive PUT price so I'm thinking to switch to Azure.

I don't however seem to be able to figure out how to sync a local directory to a remote container using `azure cli`. In particular, I have the following questions:

1- `aws` client provides a `sync` option. Is there such an option for `azure`?

2- Can I concurrently upload multiple files to Azure storage using `cli`? I noticed that there is a `-concurrenttaskcount` flag for `azure storage blob upload`, so I assume it must be possible in principle.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: No unfortunately. I ended up switching back to S3.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer the commandline and have a recent Python interpreter, the Azure Batch and HPC team has released a code sample with some [AzCopy-like functionality on Python called blobxfer](https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer). This allows full recursive directory ingress into Azure Storage as well as full container copy back out to local storage. [full disclosure: I'm a contributor for this code]

To answer your questions:

1. blobxfer supports rsync-like operations using MD5 checksum comparisons for both ingress and egress
2. blobxfer performs concurrent operations, both within a single file and across multiple files. However, you may want to split up your input across multiple directories and containers which will not only help reduce memory usage in the script but also will partition your load better

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat is the source of azure-cli, so more details can be found there. You may want to open issues to the repo :)

1. azure-cli doesn't support "sync" so far.
2. -concurrenttaskcount is to support parallel upload within a single file, which will increase the upload speed a lot, but it doesn't support multiple files yet.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload bulk files into the blob storage there is a tool provided by Microsoft [Checkout](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/)
the storage explorer allows you to do the required task..