# Is there any sync command for Azure cli similar to aws s3 sync?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to deploy a multi tier application where the angular front end from my local machine has to be uploaded to Azure blob storage container using azure cli..let me know if there is any sync command similar to aws sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure CLI now supports sync between local and Azure Blob Storage by using the azcopy sync command.

You can find more details about the azcopy sync command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync).
You can download azcopy for Windows/Linux/macOS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10).

For example, after setting up azcopy, you can use the following command:

```
azcopy sync 'C:\myDirectory' 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer' --recursive
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems that Azure CLI does not support sync currently.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905251/uploading-10-000-000-files-to-azure-blob-storage-from-linux) is a similar post, you could refer to it.

This is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage), you could post it to help to improve Azure CLI.

Comment: Thank you @joyWang